# No funciona mi procedimiento almacenado SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, tsql

Estoy realizando un stored procedure o procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server con 2 variables, una que representa la columna y otra la tabla en una consulta SELECT. Aparentemente ya arregle los errores que me marcaba pero a la hora de ejecutar el procedimiento no trae ningun resultado, solo dice "comando completado exitosamente". Que puede estar pasando?

El codigo del SP:

```
CREATE PROC variable2
@cn nvarchar(30),
@tb nvarchar(30)

As 
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql varchar(200)
SET @sql = 'SELECT' + QUOTENAME(@cn) + 'FROM' + QUOTENAME(@tb);
END;
GO
```

Ejecucion:

```
EXECUTE variable1 @cn = 'FECHAVENTAS',@tb = 'VENTAS'
```

Comment: o sea...el procedimiento almacenado está funcionando....lo que estás haciendo es asignar un valor a una variable...y nada más. Si quieres que se ejecute, tienes que usar `EXEC(@sql)` o `sp_executesql @sql` después del `SET`. Ahora, a menos que tengas control absoluto de cómo se le pasan variables a sp o sea sólo para uso interno, esto no es recomendable, te deja abierto a [sql injection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/sql-injection?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Además de lo anterior, no sé si es obvio pero en el EXECUTE estás ejecutando el SP variable1, no variable2

Comment: JYass si de hecho lo copie mal pero aun con variable 2 pasa lo mismo

Comment: sí, y pasa por lo que expliqué en mi comentario

Comment: @Lamak y entonces de que otra forma podria hacer el store procedure con 2 variables como lo planteo sin caer en lo de la inyeccion SQL como me comentas?

Comment: Por qué necesitas hacer un procedimiento almacenado donde alguien pueda pasar dinámicamente el nombre de la columna y la tabla?...así como está, no me hace mucho sentido

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que no estás indicando a tu consulta que se ejecute dentro de tu procedure, puesto que con `set` asignas valores. Ni tampoco estarías conociendo que se está ejecutando en caso de que tus variables se añaden de alguna funcionalidad externa de c# o de otra procedencia

tendrias que hacer algo como esto

```
CREATE PROC variable2
@cn nvarchar(30),
@tb nvarchar(30)

As 
BEGIN
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT' + + ' ' + QUOTENAME(@cn) + ' ' + 'FROM' + ' ' + QUOTENAME(@tb)
EXECUTE (@sql)
END
```

Comment: Te veo criticando pero no proponiendo algo mejor. Parece ser que no todos entienden que esto es una plataforma para apoyar a otros, no para sacar la soberbia que llevamos dentro. @LuisCazares

Comment: @LuisCazares Muchos de los que estamos acá fuimos y somos principiantes, quizás usted esté en un estado más avanzado de conocimiento, Erick con el pasar de los días entenderá por qué no podría aplicar esta query.  En este caso se Requiere de una solución con la que es posible aclarar su duda. En caso contrario tu por poseer un conocimiento mayor te invito a guiarlo e indicarle cual es la solución más óptima para resolver el inconveniente.

Comment: Precisamente porque hay principiantes aquí es que pido que no se publique mal código. No se trata de que aprendan mal y luego traten de aprender de nuevo. Se trata de que los principiantes obtengan un conocimiento de calidad desde el inicio. Si alguien te pregunta como se puede disparar en el pie, no vas a enseñarle como ¿o sí?

Comment: Y no se trata de soberbia, se trata de seguridad al momento de programar. No veo que se responda la pregunta de Lamak para saber por que es necesario realizar algo así. Ese código es simplemente una mala idea y algo que no debería existir. Hay muchas razones para usar código dinámico pero esta no es una de ellas.

Comment: y cual es tu solución? @LuisCazares

Comment: Mi solución sería no utilizar código dinámico y escribir los procedimientos almacenados correctos. Otra opción, sería implementar un ORM que maneje este tipo de consultas.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución.

Lo primero un escenario:

```
Create table Ventas (FechaVentas date, otraColumna int)
Go 
Insert into Ventas (FechaVentas, otraColumna)
values
(GETDATE(), 1),
(GETDATE(), 2);
go
```

Con una tabla creada, modificamos el procedimiento, en varios pequeños detalles:

```
CREATE PROC variable3
@cn nvarchar(30),
@tb nvarchar(30)

As 
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(200)
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@cn) + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tb) + N';';
END;
Exec sp_executeSql @sql;
GO
```

La variable @sql es de tipo nvarchar, no porque sea obligatorio, sino porque el procedimiento almacenado sp_executeSQL, recibe una variable de este tipo, y por tanto todos los literales, que se concatenan a la variable son `N`.

Además se incluye la ejecución dinámica de la sentencia.

```
EXECUTE variable3 @cn = 'FECHAVENTAS',@tb = 'VENTAS'
```

La ejecución del mismo produce.

[image: resultado]

Normalmente cuando trabajes con código SQL Dínamico, prueba primero a incluir en vez de `Exec sp....`, un `print @sql`. Luego mandas ejecutar el procedure y te devolverá la sentencia que intentará ejecutar. Esto te provee de más información.

Si observas realmente la sentencia, he incluido espacios entre la columna y From y la tabla, y he terminado la sentencia con un punto y coma.

Además te recomiendo que intentes parametrizar la ejecución del procedimiento sp_executeSQL

[Parametrizar exec sp_ExecuteSql](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2021/02/03/sql-dinamico-como-se-hace/)